# Ошибка при запуске проекта на Django

Tags: python, django

Столкнулся с этой ошибкой. Я посещал форумы, официальную документацию и исправить не смог.

[image: Это ошибка]

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', 'learning_logs.urls', name='learning_logs',
         ),
]
#код learning_log/urls.py
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Прямо в тексте ошибки написано в чём проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`learning_logs.urls` не является представлением (то есть функцией). Если Вы хотите включить `urls.py` Вашего приложения, то должны делать это с помощью `include`.

***Код:***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

Comment: `namespace` это именованный аргумент функции `include`, [примеры](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#id5).

Comment: @avtomato Спасибо за замечание, опечатался.

Answer (score 2):

Скажем так, вы плохо читали документацию. 
[Django Tutorial #1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/)

```
# urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Сравниваем с вашим кодом и видим, что у вас нет `include`. Воспользуйтесь функцией и все заработает

Comment: после того когда я сделал все как у вас у меня появилась новая ошибка:TypeError: _path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'